# Perl modules for cgi

Tags: perl, perl-module

What Perl modules should I look into using for processing forms, and for interfacing with databases (oracle and mysql) (and as a bonus the perl toolkit).  It's been 10 years. Back then I used:
    use CGI;
    $query = new CGI;
    use DBI;
    use tk;
    use tk::pretty;

Would someone tell me the successor modules to these older mod's, especially the CGI modules, or at least the ones that are recommended for CGI and databases?
thanks
Reggie

Answer (score 0):

Though old the best module used for processing forms and DB will be `use CGI qw(:standard)` and `use DBI` which are the standard methods.
We can look into `Form::Processor` along with the DB integration by using `Form::Processor::Model::CDBI`

For further knowledge please follow through this post which helps a lot.

```
[http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=644032]
```